# Why this shallow copy is happening between two different objects in angular 5?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two different variables :

1. gVar(service)
2. fVar(locally defined variable)

I had used two approaches (second approach solves my problem but still I don't know what causes the problem in first approach).

***FirstApproach:***

Service is used in class **serviceConsume.ts** by **DI** in the following way:

```
 private fVar: any = {};
 constructor(       
    private gVar: GlobeVar,
    ) {

    this.fVar = this.gVar.$fVar;
    }
```

and the **gVar.ts** is a service defined as:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

Injectable()
export class GlobeVar {
  private fVar: any = {};
  private Step: any;

  public get $Step(): any {
    return this.Step;
  }

  public set $Step(value: any) {
    this.Step = value;
  }

  public get $fVar(): any {
    return this.fVar;
  }

  public set $fVar(value: any) {
    this.fVar = value;
  }


  public clear() { 
    this.$fVar = null;
  }
}
```

Now my question is if I make assignment in following way in my serviceConsume.ts class

```
this.fVar.Step = null;
```

It also makes **this.gVar.$fVar.Step** also **null** ...HOW?

***Second Approach:***

But if i make assignment in my serviceConsume.ts class file in this way:

```
constructor(       
private gVar: GlobeVar,
) {
 Object.assign(this.fVar, this.gVar.$fVar);
 }
```

then shallow copy does not take place.

I want to know

1. How shallow copy is taking place during assignment in first
   approach.
2. What is the best way to avoid shallow copy (if i need not
   want to use object.assign).
3. Is my second approach right?

Thanks in advance for your all attention and efforts.If someone can explain/hint me on this; I personally think that you have mastered JavaScript/typescript or angular for sure.

Comment: In the code you posted your `fVar` does not have a property `Step`, so of cause it's null or undefined.

Comment: The var `fVar.Step = null` is right ; i wanted to know that how this assignment makes `this.gVar.$fVar.Step` also **null**.

Comment: Did you before checking assign another value than null to `this.gVar.$fVar.Step`?

Comment: Yes @Fussel any value assigned will be reflected to the `this.gVar.$fVar.Step` also

Comment: Yea, I just tried it on stackblitz. Interessting. Well, my guess is that the getter method returns more of a reference (so both variables point to the same object in memory) than an independend one for each variable while `Object.assign` is creating a new independend copy for your variable. Didn't know this could happen in JS/TS, but your 2nd approach should be fine if you want independent objects.

Comment: @Fussel thank you so much for your attention and letting me know the possible cause.Can you also suggest things to keep in mind for future to avoid such things and please share your stackblitz link too if possible.